# How to combine terms for a truth table containing two outputs

Tags: boolean-algebra

here's my truth table:

```
A   B   C   D   Z1  Z2
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   1   0
0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   1   1   0
0   1   0   0   0   1
0   1   0   1   1   1
0   1   1   0   0   1
0   1   1   1   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   1   1   0
1   1   0   0   0   1
1   1   0   1   0   0
1   1   1   0   0   1
1   1   1   1   1   1
```

How do I combine each single row's boolean expression for Z1 and Z2 into a larger term? And can you please provide a direct example of how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by combining Boolean expressions? Also your table has only fourteen entries, not sixteen.

Comment: The comment of @ParclyTaxel is *double-edged*.  On the one hand, with 4 input variables, A,B,C,D there are 16 possible variations (i.e. $2^4$) and you have only shown 14.  Overlooking that, as I see it, the problem is to find a rule that determines $z_1$ in terms of A,B,C,D.  For example, the rule $D=1 \implies z_1 = 1$ won't do, because of the data in row 8.  Presumably, you are also supposed to do the same thing for $z_2$.

Comment: @user2661923 some rows $A,B,C,D$ are duplicated too...

Comment: Re @ParclyTaxel's last comment (a point that I overlooked), your 3rd and 5th row give the same input values for A,B,C,D but different output values for $z_2.$  I am guessing that one of those two rows has a typo.